# Unable to write data on firebase even after successful attempt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to write some data on the database for my web but even after showing the alert for data posted successfully, the data isn't getting uploaded to the firebase. It was working fine before I tried to add the functionality for getting the images uploaded to the firebase storage. The code didn't work fine so I deleted it but ever since that I am unable to write data into the firebase. Below is my code please have a look.

Javascript code:-

```
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
const customText = document.getElementById("custom-text");

customBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    realFileBtn.click();
});
realFileBtn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    if (realFileBtn.value) {
        customText.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value;
    }else{
        customText.innerHTML = "No file chosen, yet.";
    }
});

$("#createBtn").click(
    function(){

        var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/');
        alert(databaseRef);

        var Title = $("#tit").val();
        var desc =  $("#dees").val();



        if (Title !="" && desc != "") {
            var uid =  firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;
            alert(uid);
            var data = {
                Title: Title,
                desc: desc,
                push: uid

            };
            var updates = {};
            updates['/posts/' + uid] = data;
            alert(updates);
            firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

            alert("You blog posted successfully!");  

            window.location.reload(); 
        }else{
            alert("All fields are necessary!"); 
        }




    }
    );
```

Please have a look.

The alert for databaseRef is displayed, the alert for uid is displayed, the alert for data successfully posted is displayed but still the data isn't getting stored in the firebase real time database.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Using different tags were only meant to spread the thread wide to get the solution as soon as possible being a android developer I am fully aware of the difference, this community for people who can help others to solve problems whom they aren't able to solve by themselves, so I would really appreciate it if you could help me instead of pinpointing my mistakes.

Comment: If the tag is not directly relevant to your question, please do not add it - wanting a solution quicker is not a valid excuse for deliberate mistagging.

Comment: Sir, right now I am too much into solving this error as soon as I can, so maybe what u are saying is right but I don't have that much time for this. Appreciate your concern but getting rid of this error is more important for me than worrying about mistagging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you forgot to add a callback function when calling `update()`. Lets take a closer look at these two lines of code:

```
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
alert("You blog posted successfully!");
```

It's easy to think that if the `update()` function call returns it's a sign that the update completed successfully. But that's not the case. In order for the Firebase Javascript API to communicate with the Firebase database it needs to submit an HTTP request, and in JavaScript that can only be done asynchronously.

In the Firebase API [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update), the function *signature* for `update()` is `update(values, onComplete)` which then goes on to state *returns firebase.Promise containing void*.

This means a call to `update()` returns before the update has actually happened. To take an action when the update actually happens you need to either provide a callback function for the `onComplete` parameter, or use the [Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise) API, which is the value returned by `update()`.

### Example using Promise API

```
firebase.database().ref().update(updates).then(function() {
    alert("You blog posted successfully!");
}, function(error) {
    alert("Oops, something went wrong!" + error);
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help at least now I know where I may have messed up but I was trying to implement it and I think I wansn't able to do it can you gimme a slight hint by optimizing my code a bit.